# i2cdetect addresses 7-bit or 8-bit?

Tags: i2cdetect, i2c

Are the addresses reported by `i2cdetect` 7-bit or 8-bit I2C addresses? My hope is the more general 7-bit address.

I'm starting to run some experiments, but it would be nice if the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/i2cdetect.8.html) were a bit more explicit about the reported format.

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -y 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1d -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- 61 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: There is no mention of `8-bit slave address` in I2C spec https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf

Comment: 8-bits is when the 7-bit address is left-shifted one bit and a r/w or indication bit is added.  From experiments, pretty sure these are 7-bit addresses being reported because that lsb is a mix of 0 and 1 in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my experiments say the same, they are 7 bits addresses, for example `i2cdetect` returns you `0x33` (`0b00110011`), however physically on the bus you will see:

- `0x66` (`0x33<<1` and LSB set to `0`) master will send data to the slave
- `0x67` (`0x33<<1` and LSB set to `1`) master will read the data from the slave